# $\big\{\sin(ax) + b\;\big|\; a > 0$ and $\;b\;$ belongs to $[c,d]$ where $c,d > 0\big\}$ is compact in the space $\;C\big[0,1\big]\;$?

Tags: compactness, normed-spaces

How to show if $\;\big\{\sin(ax) + b\;\big|\; a > 0$ and $\;b\;$ belongs to $[c,d]$ where $c,d > 0\big\}$ is either compact or not compact in the space $\;C\big[0,1\big]\;$ with the supremum norm?

I'm really not sure where to start!

Comment: Let $F$ be the set of functions in question. Suppose $F$ is compact. The assumption $c \leq b \leq d$ implies $F \subset C([0, 1], [c - 1, d + 1])$. It is a result that if $X, Y$ are compact and $\mathcal{F} \subset C(X, Y)$ is compact, then $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous, and therefore uniformly equicontinuous since $X$ is compact. This implies $F$ is compact. Now the derivatives of functions in $F$ are unbounded, so it seems likely that $F$ is not uniformly equicontinuous, but I have not formally verified this.